# Spring JPA repository use @IdClass

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-jpa

With an entity like this:

```
public class AccountId implements Serializable {
  private int a;
  private int b;

  // getters, setters, etc.
}

@Entity
@IdClass(AccountId.class)
public class Account implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private int a;
  @Id
  private int b;

  // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Is it possible to write a standard JPA repository with composite key (`AccountId`):

```
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, AccountId> {
  void findByCompositeIdAnd<some other conditions>(AccountId accountId, <other paramters>);
}
```

instead of key components (`a` and `b`):

```
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, AccountId> {
  void findByCompositeIdAnd<some other conditions>(int a, int b, <other paramters>);
}
```

I'd like to avoid using `@EmbeddedId` to cut on verbosity or writing custom `@Query`s.

Comment: @BahattinUngormus Looks like it does, thanks!